# Why does the destination ViewController not get added to the navigation stack when segueing to it using 'push' style?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with 3 tabs.
In the 1st tab, there is button which leads to `NoteViewController` when tapped.

`NoteViewController` is a TableViewController with **static** cells; `NoteViewController` is embedded in its navigation controller.

**My Goal**: One of the static cells of `NoteViewController` (when tapped) needs to go to another `TableVC` in the 2nd tab which is also embedded its own navigation controller. For segue, I just use a segue from the storyboard and set the style to `push`.

**Problem**:
When segue seems to work fine, that `TableVC` doesnt become a part of the navigation controller of `NoteViewController`, thus it doesnt have automatic backward navigation... instead it just just opens up as if it was presented modally.

What could be the reason?
If the code is needed, I can post.

Comment: If you want to navigate from a VC in one tab to a VC in another tab, you'll need to subclass `UITabBarController` and implement functions for `VC1` to tell the controller to switch to `Tab2` and tell `Tab2` controller to push to another VC. Not difficult, but it can lead to confusing navigation for the user.

Comment: I hope my idea was clear because I am trying to create the same thing as it is for example in the Calendar native iOS app. When a user wants to create a new event, he goes to the needed scene and also finds `Calendar` cell with `disclosure indicator`, and when he taps onto it, it leads to the list of calendars (such as "work", "family") available. How to do the same thing?

Comment: In the Calendar app, when creating a new event, you are presented with a Modal View controller (a navigation controller) with a table view controller as the root. When tapping "Calendar" it **pushes within *that*** navigation controller. It doesn't switch tabs in the main tab bar interface.

Comment: In fact I would argue that pushing to a navigation stack on a different tab is bad UX, and the solution is "don't do that."

Comment: So how to navigate from one V1C in 1 tab to another VC2 in the 2nd tab? Or Should I create a 'new' similar VC with the content of VC2? Because I was worried that I would do something redundant by creating a new VC that has the same content and look as the one that already exists...

Comment: @Asol - you need to re-think the design. If the user is on `Tab1` and taps something (button, table cell, whatever) and is taken to a VC that is one (or two or 3) "pushes" deep in a nav controller in `Tab2`, the "automatic backward navigation" will ***NOT*** take them back to `Tab1` -- it will take them back *within the nav controller stack* and they'll still be in `Tab2`. Bad and confusing UX (User eXperience). You commented about making it the same as the Calendar app new event process. Why not follow that approach?